# How can I generate a QR Code of 4,296 letters?

Tags: barcode

according to http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html , QR Code can maximum hold 4,296 letters (version 40). but I tried all the online generator and some installed software, none of them can generate such a QR Code. Where can I find one software supporting this?

Answer (score 2):

I found out the reason. For version 40, alphanumeric content is restricted as: http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/alphanumeric-table ...only uppercase letters are allowed.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I found that using base32 encoding the 4296 limit is reached as it only uses uppercase letters. I used this library to encode my data: https://github.com/rnewman/base32-standalone. With base64 encoding I was limited to put 2953 characters in my qr.